# How does MongoDB deal with concurrent updates?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I started to use MongoDB at work so far so good.
I was wondering though how does MongoDB deal with concurrent updates ?
I've read that there is no locking feature in MongoDB so I was wondering what is the the common practice to deal with this.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50262110/431012 explains wiredTiger (current) concurrency approach.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

MongoDB used a process wide write lock to guarantee that only one write operation (update/insert/remove) can be performed at a time. As such it automatically solves concurrency issues since write concurrency simply isn't allowed.

If 4 threads attempt an update operation one of them will take the write lock, do its update and release the lock. After that one of the remaining 3 will grab the lock, do its update, etc.

Concurrency only comes into play if your operation cannot be wrapped in a single write operation. Note that for the most common usecase (find a doc, update it and grab the new version atomically) MongoDB offers the "findAndModify" command which does just that : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command

UPDATE : Locking is more granular these days.

Comment: Thanks I do understand why it seemed common knowledge.

Comment: You're welcome. It seems like a limiting feature but because writes are relatively fast it's actually rarely a performance issue. Keep an eye on "locked %" in mongostat to see how much of the time is spent with the lock held.

Comment: MongoDb 3.2 onwards The WiredTiger storage engine is the default storage engine, and it supports  document-level locks for write operations. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#storage-wiredtiger.

Comment: This answer is applicable specifically to WT and explains things well https://stackoverflow.com/a/50262110/431012

Answer (score 8):

Use [modifier operations](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating):

`$inc $set $unset $push $pushAll $addToSet $pop $pull $pullAll $rename $bit`

all of them are atomic.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this article but it doesn't seem like it guaranties that you are the only one to write on a particular collection no ?

Comment: as long as you're using modifier operations it doesn't matter how many concurrent writes you have.