# MongoDB - WiredTiger Snapshots vs. Locking

Tags: database, mongodb, concurrency, wiredtiger

I am not completely understanding how these two features relate to one another in a (WiredTiger) MongoDB program:

*1) WiredTiger Snapshots*

*2) Data Locking*

If each read operation using the WiredTiger engine is, at read-time, provided with a database level 'snapshot' (so as to create consistency (the C in ACID), why then, do we also need locking? Let's use an example.

I perform a query at the Document level (a read operation). Okay, so I know I get the database level snapshot, so that my data is consistent **EVEN IF** another user is concurrently writing to that same Document, updating it.

So at this point, what is the use for having a Shared-Lock on that document, which is blocking all write (exclusive) operations on that document until the Shared-Lock is released? What could possibly go wrong in writing to that Document concurrently while I'm reading it, if I am, in fact, using a snapshot of the Document that was provided to me at read-time? Why would I care if the Document is locked during my read-operation period or not? I already have my (consistent) data from that point-in-time, no?

I'm obviously missing a key concept here... Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right that the read operation will acquire a snapshot. When using the WiredTiger storage engine, MongoDB does *not* lock individual documents for either reads or writes. Instead WiredTiger uses Multi-Version Concurrency Control, MVCC. When performing an update of a document, that update will succeed as long as the document still has the same version as it had when acquiring the snapshot. If not, WiredTiger will return an error (WT_ROLLBACK) indicating that the update had write conflicts. In this case, the update will abort and all pending changes are undone. MongoDB will then transparently retry the operation.

Comment: GeertB, is it safe for me to conclude then that 1) Document level locking and 2) MVCC are two different protocols/tools used with the same end in mind, but that the WiredTiger team simply chose to implement the latter? And also that WiredTiger ONLY uses the latter?

Comment: Yes. Where MongoDB documentation and source code mentions "document level locking", it really means document level concurrency control: the actual method is up to each storage engine. WiredTiger indeed only uses MVCC for document level concurrency control.