# How to handle multiple NodeJS requests reading and updating the same mongoDB document at the same time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, concurrency

I am using mongoDB along with Nodejs. Whenever I get a request from Nodejs, I read a document from MongoDB collection, perform some mathematical calculations on it and then update the document based on those calculations.

The problem is that if I send 5 requests at the same time, then all the requests read the same data and therefore the updates made to the document are not correct.

How can I solve this issue? I tried reading on the documentation but didn't get any clue.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-update-if-current) help?

Comment: maybe it is same in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997835/how-does-mongodb-deal-with-concurrent-updates